# Android bitmap paint size widget

Tags: android, typeface

I'm new on android and I've made an widget that shows battery % but on my phone (Galaxy nexus) shows fine, but on other with different density it shows very big. I've search already in every place but I didnt found any solution that makes the build bitmap shows good in every mobile... can someone please help me?

```
public Bitmap buildBitmap(String texto, Context context) {

    Bitmap myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(94, 94, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
            "batmfont.ttf");

    Paint paint = new Paint();

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setSubpixelText(true);
    paint.setTypeface(font);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setTextSize(35);
    paint.setShadowLayer(1, 1, 1, Color.rgb(51, 51, 51));
    paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);

    Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas(myBitmap);
    myCanvas.drawText(texto, 47, 54, paint);

    return myBitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Get the screen dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/how-to-get-screen-dimensions) and [Resize a bitmap](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2009/12/25/resizing-a-bitmap/).

So based on your device size you can display bitmap.

Comment: So, 1st I declare that DisplayMetrics, 2nd my build bitmap and 3rd I resize bitmap? Can I make all this on service or in my widget class?